# Polymer content displaying as desktop on tablet

Tags: polymer, media-queries, polymer-1.0, tablet, polymer-starter-kit

I wonder if anyone has any media query advice that might resolve my issue? I'm trying out the ace Polymer Project's Starter Kit (I'm very new to Polymer) and am finding that the tablet media queries in app-theme.html don't work when displaying content on a Lenovo Yoga Tab 3, 10.1".

Rather than showing the requisite mobile layout and styling the device, instead, displays the desktop version (badly, as you can see).

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esynf.jpg)

I can go in and ensure the drawer is collapsed across all devices by using 'force narrow' but that still doesn't solve the problem of the tablet screen being perceived as a desktop, which means it fails to take advantage of the 'meta theme' facility in Chrome (whereby the url bar takes on the colour of the Web app).

Apols for such an elementary (no pun intended) question but I'd really appreciate being pointed in the right direction. Cheeeeeeeers! :)

Comment: Does it happen when you visit other polymer sites like https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?package=app-elements ?

Comment: Thanks for responding Manolo... I've managed to solve the problem, I think :)

Comment: Damn, I've had to delete the 'solution' I posted as I've just discovered that it doesn't solve the issue after all :(  Still searching...

Answer (score 0):

Finally sorted... I think :) After some intensive digging around I found [**this**](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/issues/189) immensely handy info on GitHub.

Acting upon it, in the Starter Kit's index.html I changed:-

```
<paper-drawer-panel id="paperDrawerPanel" responsive-width="840px">
```

to:-

```
<paper-drawer-panel id="paperDrawerPanel" responsive-width="1280px">
```

All seems to work just fine, now :)